# Why "type cd" on Mac OS states that "cd is a function"?

Tags: macos, bash, terminal, command-line-interface, cd

On Mac OS Yosemite, I type the following:

```
Max:~ Max$ type cd
cd is a function
cd ()
{
    __zsh_like_cd cd "$@"
}
Max:~ Max$
```

I thought `cd is a shell builtin`. Why is that? Can someone elaborate on that?

Comment: This is because somewhere `cd` has been defined as function. Use `typeset -f` to see all of them and you can look for `.bashrc` or files like that in your HOME directory to change them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @fedorqui says this is because something has created a `cd` function to override the alias.

This specific one appears to come from [`rvm`](https://github.com/wayneeseguin/rvm/blob/master/scripts/extras/bash_zsh_support/chpwd/load.sh).

Comment: Thx! Indeed, I installed `rvm` a while ago.

Comment: Welcome. For the record while I knew I'd seen that `__zsh_like_cd` somewhere before I couldn't remember where but a simple online search found it for me.